# Invalid Column Name on a stored procedure (Silverlight WCF)

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework

I have a Silverlight 4 apps that use the entity framework with WCF RIA.

All of a sudden a few (I think 3) stored procedures stop working.  Every users reprot the same problem All of them has the error message when the Silverlight app tries to execute the related query.

> Load operation failed for query 'SomeStoredProcedure'. An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details. InnerException message: Invalid column name
>   'someColumn'.
>
> at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>
> at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetEnumeratorInternal()
>
> at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainService.Enumerate[T](IEnumerable
>   enumerable, Int32 estimatedResultCount)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainService.Query(QueryDescription
>   queryDescription, IEnumerable`1& validationErrors, Int32& totalCount)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.QueryProcessor.Process[TEntity](DomainService
>   domainService, DomainOperationEntry queryOperation, Object[]
>   parameters, ServiceQuery serviceQuery, IEnumerable`1&
>   validationErrors, Int32& totalCount)
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.QueryOperationBehavior`1.QueryOperationInvoker.InvokeCore(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)

Now the weird thing is:

- I have a development deployment of the same app, and that works fine when connecting to the production database.
- If I connect to the SSMS and execute the stored procedure, it returns the correct data.
- So what I did was simply recompile the stored procedure.  I basically select the stored procedure, click Modify.  It will generate the ALTER PROCEDURE script, I just hit execute without changing anything inside.  Now suddenly all three stored procedures work fine again, even though I only recompile one of them.

To explain this better, this is what happen in sequential order:

1. The Silverlight app suddenly complain some SP does not contain some column
2. Runs the SP in SSMS, returns normal and expected result.
3. Recompile the SP
4. Runs the SP in SSMS, returns the exact same result as #2.
5. The Silverlight app works again

What is going on?

Comment: sounds like someone modified the SP outside of source control

Comment: No it doesn't - I compared it.

Comment: check if procedures return the same results. May be one of the stored procedures does not return any results instead of the empty result set?

Comment: Yes they do return the normal result all the time.  Please see my edit.

Comment: Did one of the columns in the table change from NOT NULLABLE to NULLABLE and back again?  Or vs versa?  That would explain this. Or a change in data type.

Comment: There was no change to the database structure when all fo this happens.  Not even smaller things like length, nullable, index, trigger....